# Pairing vs Master-slave between BT Module to BT Module

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, bluetooth, digital-communications, bluetooth-low-energy

If I take two identical BT modules, for example HC05 or HC06 then is it possible to pair the two modules with each other or is it like you need 1 master and 1 slave module for pairing?

Edit:
Now I have found some more details about the BT modules. They have 'AT' command set by which they can be configured using any 'Terminal' software from PC. Following references contains very good details about this:

1. [BT AT Command Mode](https://www.instructables.com/id/AT-command-mode-of-HC-05-Bluetooth-module/)
2. [BT IO Specs PDF](http://www.spezial.cz/pdf/BT_IO_Specification.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about BT modules, which is the **hardware** (there's some software inside but let's just ignore that).

Such a BT module can behave as a Master or as a Slave.

Pairing has nothing to do with the hardware, pairing is like a "handshake" and is fully controlled by the software.

The Master or Slave behavior of this hardware is defined by the **software**. So it depends on what software you load in the module or the software running on some other device which controls the BT module, if the BT module behaves as a Master or as a Slave.

Comment: As far as I know if I buy two identical BT modules HC-05 or HC-06 or HM-10 then these modules have software already flashed in their ROMs. Then is it possible to change their Master or Slave status so that they can communicate with each other?

Comment: That software inside the ROM is the firmware, this firmware **does not** 
determine if the module is a Master or a Slave. You should have a look at some projects using BT modules to see how they're supposed to be used. There are no master or slave modules, a module can be used as Master or slave depending on how you control it.

Comment: OK, now I understand your point. Finally it means that to communicate 2 BT modules then one of them has to be in Master mode and other in Slave mode. I hope my understanding is correct upto this point. Kindly correct my knowledge if not correct.